How can we prove that there exists a $0\neq v\in\Bbb C^n$ such that $Av=av, Bv=bv$.

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ complex matrices, $AB=BA$. $a,b\in\Bbb C$ satisfies: if the polynomial $f(x,y)$ verifies that $f(A,B)=0$, then $f(a,b)=0$. How can we prove that there exists a $0\neq v\in\Bbb C^n$ such that $Av=av, Bv=bv$.

My attempt: Using the characteritic polynomial, we see $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $b$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.
And $AB=BA$ implies that $A,B$ has a same eigenvector. This is well-known.
All is not known is that: whether or not $a$ is the unique eigenvalue of $A$, or $b$ is the unique eigenvalue of $B$. If so, it conclude.
Help.

Let $p(x)=\prod_{i}(x-a_i)^{n_i}$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, then $p(A)=O$, therefore $f(x,y):=p(x)$ vanishes at $x=A, y=B$, and by the given condition, $p(a)=0$. Therefore $a$ is indeed an eigenvalue of $A$.
Let $q(x)=\prod_{a_i\not=a}(x-a_i)^{n_i}\in\mathbb C[x]$. Since $p(x)$ is minimal, $q(A)\not=O$, and let $W\not=\{0\}$ be the range of $q(A)$, which is also the generalized eigenspace for eigenvalue $a$ of $A$. Since $A, B$ commute, $W$ is an invariant subspace of $B$. Let $r(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $B|_W$. Now let $f(x,y)=q(x)r(y)$, then for all $v$, $f(A, B)v=r(B)q(A)v=r(B|_{W})q(A)v=0$, hence $$f(A,B)=O\Rightarrow f(a,b)=0\Rightarrow q(a)r(b)=0\Rightarrow r(b)=0$$
Therefore $B|_W$ has $b$ as an eigenvalue. Let $w\in W$ be an eigenvector of $B|_W$ with eigenvalue $b$, let $n$ be the maximal natural number such that $v:=(A-a)^nw\not=0$.
therefore $(A-a)v=0$, and $$Bv = B (A-a)^n w = (A-a)^n Bw = (A-a)^nbw = b (A-a)^nw=bv$$
Note that we actually only need the weaker condition: for any pair of polynomials in one variable, if $p(A)q(B)=O$ then $p(a)q(b)=0$ (equivalent to $p(a)=0$ or $q(b)=0$).
